Timecockpit Web API: How do I get a list of UserDetail's, not only mine?
For my work, I have to work with the Timecockpit Web API. But I never worked with it. I have to create a list of users with their ActualHoursOfWork, Deviation and the PlannedHoursOfWork of a given timespan, for example for august.
As I sad I never worked with the Timecockpit API, in fact, I don't rely with APIs in general. The documentation is pretty extensive, but in my opinion, a lot of basic details are left out.
I worked through the documentation and found the following query:
{ "query": "From U In UserDetail Select New With {.User = U, .PlannedHoursOfWork = :PlannedHoursOfWork(U.UserDetailUuid, #2024-08-01#, #2024-08-31#, True), .ActualHoursOfWork = :ActualHoursOfWork(U.UserDetailUuid, #2024-08-01#, #2024-08-31#, True), .Deviation = :ActualHoursOfWork(U.UserDetailUuid, #2024-08-01#, #2024-08-31#, True) - :PlannedHoursOfWork(U.UserDetailUuid, #2024-08-01#, #2024-08-31#, True)}", "parameters": {} }
This query gives me the ActualHoursOfWork, Deviation and the PlannedHoursOfWork from august of my user. But I did not find how to rewrite this query to get the UserDetail's of multiple users. Idirly, I would like the details of users asigned to one specific department.
